# Facing problem while trying trying to rotate SVG animation

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm a beginner in animation. I am trying to learn svg animation from the following piece of code.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="50 70 200 200">
         
<path stroke="black" fill="none" d="M70,85H125V140H70V85Z" ></path>
            
<path d="M0,0 L-2.69,-4.95L0,-2.2L2.69,-4.95L0,0z" transform="rotate(-90)" style="fill: #ff0000;">                              
<animateMotion path="M70,85H125V140H70V85Z" dur="10s" rotate="auto"  repeatCount="indefinite"></animateMotion>
</path> 
  
<g> 
  <desc>white mask</desc>
<rect x="90" y="80" width="15" height="65" fill="white"  />
<rect x="65" y="105" width="65" height="15" fill="white" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I'm tring to move the arrow to rotate in opposite direction (i.e anticlockwise) but unable to achieve that. I have tried to change the path but I'm stuck at this point.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use keyTimes and keyPoints to run the animation backwards and alter the transform to rotate the arrow. See how the keyPoints go from 1 to 0.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="50 70 200 200">
         
<path stroke="black" fill="none" d="M70,85H125V140H70V85Z" ></path>
            
<path d="M0,0 L-2.69,-4.95L0,-2.2L2.69,-4.95L0,0z" transform="rotate(90)" style="fill: #ff0000;">                              
<animateMotion keyPoints="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" path="M70,85H125V140H70V85Z" dur="10s" rotate="auto"  repeatCount="indefinite"></animateMotion>
</path> 
  
<g> 
  <desc>white mask</desc>
<rect x="90" y="80" width="15" height="65" fill="white"  />
<rect x="65" y="105" width="65" height="15" fill="white" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is it possible to rotate the arrow too?

Comment: Arrow is pointing to the opposite direction of its movement... Is it possible to rotate it in the direction of motion.

Comment: Actually this seems to be a Chrome bug. Try it in Firefox where it works correctly.

Comment: Yes, Its working fine in Firefox, So Is their any workaround for Chrome

Comment: No idea. You could always report the bug to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list). You could even download the source code and fix it if you could figure out how.

Comment: I will report it. Thanks for your time!